# php safe_mode_exec_dir help

Tags: php, shell, safe-mode, php-ini

I am hoping to find some more information about this PHP setting, I assume I need to change its value in the php.ini but I set the root the folder as `/file/path/` or as `http://www.domain.com/file/path`?

Any advice would be great

Comment: I'm not sure what are you trying, check phpinfo() output before changing anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`safe_mode_exec_dir` needs to be set to a filesystem path. It can also contain multiple paths separated by semicolon.

However, note that safe mode is [deprecated and will be removed in PHP 6](http://php.net/manual/en/features.safe-mode.php):

> This feature has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 5.3.0. Relying on this feature is highly discouraged.

if you need added security in your PHP environment, there are better approaches like the [Hardened PHP project](http://www.hardened-php.net/)'s [Suhosin](http://www.hardened-php.net/suhosin/) patch.